# search my locations with Google places api

Tags: google-places-api

I have added 100 locations to google places using google place api.Now i want to know the number of locations that i have added to google places.
So my question is that Is google provides the api that will show only the number of locations that i have added with my api key ?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible without keeping your own tally of added places. If you think that this would be a useful feature please add a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).